# Inserting an embedded document into MongoDB with angularJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

When trying to insert an embedded document, what should the angular view look like?

This is my model in node:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  /*other fields that aren't relavent here */
  allowed_countries:[CountrySchema]
});

var CountrySchema = new Schema({
  country: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  }
});
```

This is what I tried for the Angular View:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="allowed_countries.country">Allowed Countries</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="allowed_countries.country" id="allowed_countries.country">
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this isn't working but I'm not sure why how are you supposed to sort out the view for a subdocument in Angular (my google-fu is failing me)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, what do you want to achieve / what should the view perform?

Comment: Sorry, this is from the create view. I want to insert the country into the allowed_countries array. For now, I only need to do it for one country but I'm not certain how to structure it.

Comment: should  this insertion be permanent into DB (if so how it should be triggered)?

Comment: Yes. This is created when the document is created. If I change the allowed_countries field into a string ads change the data-ng-model and id to allowed_countries then the entire document is created without issue.